# configuring the optionmenu in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I want to make the optionmenu larger with a larger font but I am getting an error on using configure

Below is the code. (configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given)

Thanks in advance for your time

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
variable = StringVar(root)
root = Tk()
hoices = ['1', '2', '3']
SiteIdMenu = OptionMenu(root, variable, *choices)
SiteIdMenu.place(x=20, y=50)
SiteIdMenu.configure('Helvetica', 14)
```

Comment: Is `hoices = ['1', '2', '3']` a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:
http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-option-database.htm

And try `font = 'Helvetica'` instead of just the font name. With configure you need to add the option name or whatever the official term is. The same goes for font size.